# query to select from a table which is a value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to write a query as below? The 'column4' in inner query is a table name, and I want to use it in outer query

```
select x.column1, x.column2, x.column3, d.column5
    from (select 
        a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, b.column4
    from 
        table1 a inner join table2 b on a.priKeyCol = b.prikeyCol
    )x
    inner join column4 d on x.column2 = d.priColKey
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to look at using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to create a view that sits on all the tables you could possibly join.

```
create view UnifiedTables
as 
select *,'Table1' as TableName from table1
union all 
select *,'Table2' as TableName from table2
union all
select *,'Table3' as TableName from table3
```

And then you can join this `UnifiedTables` in your main query.

```
select t1.c1 t1c1, t1.c2 t1c2, t1.c3 t1c3, 
       ut.c1 utc1, ut.c2 utc2, ut.c3 utc3 
from table1 t1
join UnifiedTables ut on t1.c4 = ut.TableName
```

But this is a hack which probably won't solve your problem at a larger scale.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to select from a table and the table name is a value from another table.

Comment: @fn79 I know. What do you think I'm providing?